# AOC I2269VW Driver Dell 5500

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I am trying to get my new AOC I2269VW monitor to work with my Dell 5500. I tried installing this driver, but the screen still does not come on.

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

It appears my laptop recognizes the monitor but not vice-versa. The monitor works with my Macbook Air 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I bought a DVI-HDMI Amazon adapter, plugged it in, and nothing happened. Then I closed the laptop, opened the laptop and when the screen of the laptop turned on suddenly the monitor began mirroring the screen on the laptop. I then performed the same procedure from the with the VGA adapter that had seemed to be failing before and it worked too. 
I would suggest trying to open an close the laptop when using Linux with an AOC monitor after connecting the monitor to the Linux laptop. This is not necessary for Windows or Mac, but I guess for the Linux driver to register, this operation needs to be performed.